# Eclipse IDE for (Embedded C/C++) Developers 2020-12: Classic dark theme deep black color background and text in menu

Tags: eclipse, menu, themes, eclipse-cdt, background-color

Problem with dark classic theme in Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) for C/C++. Menu have all black color:

[image: Problem with dark classic theme in Eclipse 2020 12. Menu have all black color, top panel have the same]

Top panel has the same problem:

[image: top panel the same problem]

Comment: The second screenshot looks to me the same as the first one.

Answer (score 2):

That's a **bug** of Eclipse TMF which is contained by default in the

- *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers* and the
- *Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developers*

**in Eclipse 2020-12** (4.18) that has **already been fixed**:

[**Eclipse bug 569790** - [dark] Dark mode issue when Trace Compass is installed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569790)

Unfortunately, this bug was detected and fixed only shortly after the 2020-12 release. So I created the following (unofficial) **update site** that can be used to get the **patched Eclipse TMF** (via *Help > Install New Software...*):

[<s>`https://howlger.github.io/Dark-Theme-Fix-for-Eclipse-2020-12-with-TMF/update`</s>](https://howlger.github.io/Dark-Theme-Fix-for-Eclipse-2020-12-with-TMF/update)

**Update:** the **official update site** has been [published in the meantime](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569790#c20):

[**`https://download.eclipse.org/tracecompass/stable/repository/`**](https://download.eclipse.org/tracecompass/stable/repository/)

**Alternatively**, you can **use another dark theme** instead of the built-in dark theme, such as one of the following (do not use the *Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle* since it might slow down Eclipse and can cause issues):

- [Eclipse Spectrum Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-spectrum-dark-theme)
- [Planet Themes](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/planet-themes)

Please note, a dark theme is a bit more stressful for your eyes compared to a light theme (the human eye can adapt well to dark, but works best with more light).

See also: [My GitHub project to create the update site to patch TMF](https://github.com/howlger/Dark-Theme-Fix-for-Eclipse-2020-12-with-TMF)

Comment: It's great, you the best. Thanks. It is working.  Tell me please I have some color on numbers string, when a write some code.  In last eclipse version 2020 06  that problem did not have.

Comment: Oh, I solved this problem with 'show quik diff' from submenu. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear everything is working now. I edited your question to make it easier to find for others who will face the same issue. I hope that's okay.

Comment: It is ok , Thanks