# Darkest Dark theme does not work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers on Windows 8.1. I installed Darkest Dark theme from the Marketplace, but it does not work. Upon restart, Eclipse starts with my previous theme and Darkest Dark does not even appear in Preferences window. However, when I open Marketplace again and search for it, it shows as installed. I searched but did not find an answer to this exact problem.
Any help?

Comment: Peter, what version of Eclipse are you running? If you could send us your workspace error log, that might explain why the plugin isn't working. You can email it to support@genuitec.com or create a post on our forums and we can dive deeper: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/devstyle/theme-problems/

Comment: Hi, I'm running 2020-06. The error log hasn't been modified in months. I tried registering in your forum but never received a confirmation e-mail.

Comment: I know 2020-06 is old, but the newer versions don't work for my purposes (long story). I already use Darkest Dark on Fedora and it works without any (noticeable) slow down of Eclipse.

Comment: Just want to mention that under preferences, the node to look for is "DevStyle", not Darkest Dark - in case you missed this by some chance. Now, an Eclipse installation that hasn't logged anything in months is very unusual :) Are you sure you're looking at the right log?  [workspace]/.metadata/.log file? Another option would be to start eclipse with the -clean flag, that really should force resolution errors to be logged to the file which might help.

Comment: @BrianFernandes Yes, I know that DevStyle is the submenu that has the theme options (I use it on Fedora). You're right about the log file, I was looking at [workspace]/errors.txt. So should I e-mail the whole file, or just the part with the last session?

Comment: If you started with -clean, just the last session will probably do, but it wouldn't hurt to send everything since DS was installed - your call. Do send a zip of the log though. Thanks!

Comment: @howlger Unfortunately and surprisingly, the native Eclipse dark theme is horrible (scroll bars still light while everything else is dark) and the only option is a third-party solution. Of which Darkest Dark is pretty much the only one that looks good and seems to work well for many people. About your suggestions - tried a new workspace - same thing. New version of Eclipse is not an option for now, and the current version of the plugin seems to be the only one on the Marketplace.

Comment: In Windows 10 the scrollbars are dark, even in the outdated version you are using. But you are using Windows 8, whose support by Eclipse was discontinued a few versions before the version you are using. IIRC coloring of native widget scrollbars requires a newer Windows API. Better use a light theme in a bright environment, since it's less stressful for your eyes compared to a dark theme. Most people think it's a matter of taste, but it's not. The human eye can adapt well to dark, but works best with more light. More important, do not mix light and dark themes in Windows+applications.

Comment: As it turns out, only a few Eclipse developers use the dark theme and none of the CDT developers, which caused [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455219/6505250) to be overlooked in the previous release. It also shows that non Eclipse C/C++ IDE user did test a pre-release with the dark theme and reported it. Did you report what you called horrible? My previous comments here were deleted, with which I tried, to help you, unfortunately without success. I rather spend my time making Eclipse better than trying to help you while Genuitec try to silence me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my question in case someone else has the same problem.
After e-mailing Genuitec support, it turned out the problem was a permissions issue.
So I uninstalled Darkest Dark, opened Eclipse as administrator, installed it again and now it works.

Comment: Glad it's working now Peter, thank you for following up here too.

Comment: Opening Eclipse as administrator can lead to problems later. Does installing and upgrading other plugins still work? If you didn't use a separate workspace for this, are you sure everything is working (did you check the log file)?